# Calculate the volume of the region trapped by $z^2=x^2+y^2, z=2(x^2+y^2)$

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

**Task**

> Calculate the volume of the region trapped by $z^2=x^2+y^2, z=2(x^2+y^2)$ using a triple integral.

I'm kind of lost on this one, here's my (probably wrong) attempt:

Calculate the intersection, I get $z=0 \wedge z=\frac 12$. That means the region is: $E=\{(x,y,z): x^2+y^2=1/2, z=1/2\} \cup \{(x,y,z): x^2+y^2=0\}$.

That means I should integrate the constant function $1$ over $E$ to get the volume of $E$, however, I don't think I can get a triple integral this way.

How do I proceed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I may, I come up with a simpler solution. If using a triple integral is a must then, please, ignore my answer.

If $y=0$ then we have the following two equations

$$z^2=x^2\, \, \text{ and } \, \, z=2x^2.$$

I we look at the $xz$ plane we'll see the following intersection lines (drawn only for $x\ge0$):

[image]

Now, looking at the cross section of the body and the plane determined by $\color{red}z$ then we will see the ring whose area is

$$A(z)=\pi\left(\frac z2-z^2\right).$$

The volume can be computed as follows

$$V=\int_0^{\frac12}A(z)\ dz=\frac{\pi}{48}.$$

Answer (score 2):

Your definition of the region is incorrect (though your bounds for $z$ are correct). When $0\le z\le\frac{1}{2}$, the cone lies above the paraboloid; the circle of intersection at $z=\frac{1}{2}$ is $x^2+y^2 = \frac{1}{4}$. So one definition of the region is
\begin{equation*}
  -\frac{1}{2}\le x\le \frac{1}{2},\quad
  -\sqrt{\frac{1}{4}-x^2} \le y \le \sqrt{\frac{1}{4}-x^2},\quad
  2(x^2+y^2) \le z \le \sqrt{x^2+y^2}.
\end{equation*}
If you integrate $1$ over this region, you should get the answer. However, you may wish to use a different set of coordinates to make the integral simpler.

[image]

Comment: Why do you get those bounds for $z$ instead of just $0\leq z \leq \frac 1 2$?

Comment: I just chose to integrate last over $x$. If you want to integrate last over $z$, the region is more complicated, since for each $z$ the 2D plane over which you need to integrate is an annulus, so it isn't expressed so easily in Cartesian coordinates. If you want to do it that way, use cylindrical coordinates, so the region is $0\le z\le \frac{1}{2}$, $0\le \theta\le 2\pi$, $z \le r \le \sqrt{\frac{z}{2}}$.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! Last question: how do you know it should be $2(x^2+y^2)\leq z \leq \sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ instead of $\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\leq z \leq 2(x^2+y^2)$?

Comment: You look at a plot of the surfaces (you did draw a picture, didn't you?) and observe that the cone lies above and inside the paraboloid in that region. I added a diagram to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You have a function of two variables given implicitly to you. You can find the volume between the planes using a simple double integral.

Comment: Oh, yeah, forgot to add that in the question, the problem asks to use a triple integral. I'll edit that in.

Comment: In that case you'll have wait for someone with bigger knowledge than mine to help you. I've taken a course up to Calculus II :/

Comment: No problem! Could you tell me how the double integral would look for this problem? I couldn't come up with it's expression.

Comment: Hint: let x or y be 0